# Issue with free() on memory allocated for arrays

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on learning how to properly deal with pointers, arrays etc in C. I'm a little confused on allocating the memory for them and then freeing that memory. The following is some test code I slapped together:

```
char *test[150000];
char **ptr;

for(int i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
{
    test[i] = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    test[i] = "This is a test";
    printf("test[%i] = %s located at %p\n",i,test[i],&test[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i < 150000; i++)
{
    printf("Trying to free memory from %p\n",&test[i]);
    ptr = &test[i];
    free(ptr);
    printf("Array item %i has been freed...",i);
}
```

The output yields the following:

```
[... Truncated]

test[149997] = This is a test located at 0x7fff581fbcc8
test[149998] = This is a test located at 0x7fff581fbcd0
test[149999] = This is a test located at 0x7fff581fbcd8
Trying to free memory from 0x7fff580d6d60
test2(17599,0x7fff7776f310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff580d6d60: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
sh-3.2#
```

It appears that when I try and free the pointer allocated, I get an error... Any ideas / pointers on where I'm screwing up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in multiple forms. First, giving `printf` something that isn't `void *` for `%p`. Second, freeing a string literal. Third, on the edge, freeing something you did not `malloc`. Namely trying to free a pointer to what you should be freeing (if it still contained the result of the allocation).

Comment: I've also tried free(test[i]); as well. No luck...

Comment: `test[i] = "This is a test";` --> `strcpy(test[i], "This is a test");` and `free(ptr);` --> `free(test[i]);`

Comment: Thank you!!! I was just talking on the other response about this. This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
test[i] = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
```

This is ok, except that (a) it could be written as `test[i] = malloc(15);`, and (b) you don't check whether `malloc` succeeded.

```
test[i] = "This is a test";
```

This does *not* copy the contents of the string `"This is a test"` into the memory you just allocated. Rather, it's a pointer assignment, causing `test[i]` to point to the memory for the string literal. It creates a memory leak, since you no longer have a pointer to the memory you allocated with `malloc`. You probably want to use `strcpy`.

```
...
ptr = &test[i];
free(ptr);
```

<strike>Here you `free` the memory assigned to the string literal, not the memory you allocated.</strike>

Correction: that's not what it does. It tries to `free` the pointer object itself, which doesn't even make sense. (Incidentally, the argument to `free` doesn't have to be an object name; `free(&test[i])` would be equally legal -- and equally incorrect.)

Assuming you fix the allocation problem, what you want is simply:

```
free(test[i]);
```

Comment: ahh - so, in other words, doing the string literal just put the string somewhere and memory and essentially created a new pointer to it, as apposed to using the memory I just needlessly malloc'ed in the first place? Would this change should I use strcpy to insert the data?

Comment: @JonnyWhatshisface: yes, use `strcpy()` in lieu of the assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. I have a better grasp on that now... Didn't realize assigning literals would have that affect.

Comment: If you really want every element of `test` to point to a string `"This is a test", you could just drop the `malloc`; then every element of `test` would have the same value. But that's probably not useful.

Comment: @JonnyWhatshisface: A string literal is an array expression. An array expressions, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. That's why `test[i] = "This is a test"` is a pointer assignment, not an array assignment (that plus the fact that there's no such thing as an array assignment in C).

Answer (score 0):

```
char *test[150000];
char **ptr;

for(int i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
{
test[i] = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
/*test[i] = "This is a test";*/ // Fix1
printf("test[%i] = %s located at %p\n",i,test[i],&test[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i < 150000; i++)
{
printf("Trying to free memory from %p\n",&test[i]);
/*ptr = &test[i];*/ //Fix2
free(test[i]); //Fix3
printf("Array item %i has been freed...",i);
}
```

Fix1:
Heap Memory is allocated and stored into **test[i]**. So **test[i]** has valid address.  But again **test[i]** address is overridden using this statement `test[i] = "This is a test";` If you want to copy the string into test[i] use `strcpy`.
Suppose if you like to assign like this `test[i] = "This is a test";` do not allocate dynamic memory before this & no need to free also.

Fix2&Fix3:
The allocated address is stored in `test[i]` not in &test[i]. So just free that address present in `test[i]`. No need to use intermediate variable also. If required to use intermediate variable prefer to use `char *ptr`.